# How to filter installed apps by package name?

Tags: filter, package

I want to display a filtered view (list/grid/whatever I choose) of installed apps by a specific package name.

For example, filter apps starting with package name "com.myapp.xxxx", where xxxx is not of interest at this stage.

I understand that PackageManager would be used to retrieve list of all installed apps but from there how do I filter this list?  Is there a way to query installed apps for specific package name?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**yes you can,
For eg,i filter flash player is installed or not in this code snippet.**

```
  boolean flashInstalled = false;

 try {
      PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

       ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.adobe.flashplayer", 0);
       if (ai != null)
flashInstalled = true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
     flashInstalled = false;
   }
```

Comment: TX for the sample.  I'm currently invested with LibGDX but will use this in the future.